# css3 corners with different angles and shapes

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

On my [DEMO][1] below, I've been busy developing all the styles. but not able to do it properly only using css3.
Have you got a quick or nice way to do it only in CSS3? So I can make them more dynamic?
Thanks.

[image: buttons and shapes]

Comment: This sort of question gets asked over and over again. You need to layer divs and put then on different z-indeces to show only certain parts to create shapes. Search triangle css and you will find a ton of answers.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Actually, with `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements you can simulate a couple of these with a single element.

Comment: @TheZ Interesting. Do you have a link where I could check this out?

Comment: @thatidiotguy Here's a quick one I whipped up to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/e2SVR/

Comment: @TheZ Very interesting! Still wouldn't cut it for the more complex shapes DD77 has got up there, but a nice little shortcut to overlapping divs. Thanks!

Comment: @thatidiotguy Actually, I think all of the ones up there _could_ be simulated, but it'd take some time to sit down and do them all, time I don't have right now. Feel free to play around with it though! It's quite interesting how many things pseudo elements can do. :D

Comment: sorry I didn't provide the demo before,it didn't let me. http://jsfiddle.net/3fJqZ/9/